# Optimization with linear constraints in python

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization

I need to optimize an objective function F(x1,x2,..xn) subjected to constraints of the type xi=xj. Is there any in-built function in scipy/scikit-learn to implement this?
Using SLSQP in scipy.optimize.minimize gives an error saying 'singular matrix C in lsq subproblem'

Comment: Could you not substitute one of the `x[i], x[j]` out of the problem? It would make the problem smaller.

Comment: Well I did this but it may not always be possible to do it.